# Using ob_start() in a function with variables

Tags: php

I am trying to simplify my code, I call the `ob_start();` and `ob_get_clean();` about 20 times, so to simplify the code, I have changed it from

```
ob_start();
  include ROOT."/functions/generate/header.php";
$header= ob_get_clean();
```

To `$header=get_content(ROOT."/functions/generate/header.php");`

with the function as:

```
function get_content($file){
    ob_start();
        include $file;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

But since turning the procedure into a function, I am no longer able to access the variables in the main form form the form I am calling like the `header.php` file. The variables are not available when using the function, but if I use the longer version it allows me to access the variables.

Is there a reason for this or someway to work around it?

Comment: two solutions: a: provide the variables as parameters to your function. b: use the `global` keyword.

Comment: Having a file which produces output ***and*** defines variables at the same time is madness, precisely because of this. You should not write code that must be used with `ob_start`. Separate concerns and put your output producing code in one file and your function/class/variable declaring code in another. Proper encapsulation into function/classes also does wonders.